# What is usually an American breakfast outside of the US?

Tags: usa, food-and-drink, hotels, terminology

A number of hotels outside of the US offer something they call an *American Breakfast*. What does that usually include in terms of food and beverage?

*I have seen this choice offered in a few countries but right now I am looking into what Mexicans think an American breakfast is. Have been to Mexico 8 times already but never picked that option.*

Comment: Not mentioned in the answers so far is hashbrowns, which I feel are pretty American.  Usually in some form of fried patties of potato. A Canadian breakfast by contrast seems to usually have cubed deep fried potato. So like chips/fries but in little cubes instead of long skinny sticks or such.

Comment: I wonder what they would make of a question like this over on our sister site [cooking.SE](http://cooking.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: I've added this to [my list of good example cross-site SE questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214179/154292).

Comment: Maybe but the question is not intended as *What is an American Breakfast?* which is right for cooking.SE but what do people working at hotels elsewhere think it is?

Comment: Either of those questions woul be on-topic on cooking.SE to my understanding. I'ts not an "American food only". Asking how "French" fries are made in "Amercia" would be on-topic for instance.

Comment: @hippietrail Those little cubes are known as "home fries" in the US. I have no idea why.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  Interesting, I've never heard them be called "Home Fries."  "Home Fries" to me are the thick cut wedge type fried potatoes.  At least everywhere I've lived.  The cubed ones we always called "hash browns" but they are not the same as the shredded ones, obviously.  But searching for "Home Fries" images in Google/Bing brings up an assortment of cut potatoes, some of which are more wedged, and some more cubed.   I think the reason is that they are cut "at home" and therefore not evenly cute like they would be by machine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An *American breakfast* is simply the American variant of an *[English breakfast](http://englishbreakfastsociety.com/full-english-breakfast.html)*, which is elsewhere an *[Irish breakfast](http://www.foodireland.com/recipes/Breakfast/irishbreakfast.htm)*— what Wikipedia in its neutralism calls a *[full breakfast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_breakfast)*, in contrast to the so-called *[continental breakfast](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37939/origin-of-continental-breakfast)*.

A full breakfast is a "heavy" breakfast high in animal protein such as eggs, sausage, ham, and/or bacon, often fried. The American variant will have some kind of bread such as flapjacks/pancakes, French toast, or a waffle, and American-style sausage or bacon. I have rarely seen a hotel "American" breakfast that includes genuinely American dishes like waffles and chicken, grits, or biscuits and gravy.

Comment: Right. I've seen English and Continental breakfasts in many places. Never heard of anything being called Irish breakfast though.

Comment: Plenty of places offer Irish breakfast in Australia. I'm sure about hotels because I rarely stay at hotels in developed countries. I've never been sure what the difference between Irish and English breakfast is. They're both huge and high in fat and vary from place to place.

Comment: It seems that black and white pudding are _essential_ elements of an Irish breakfast, but _optional_ in an English one. Perhaps also higher probability of baked beans in an English one vs Irish one? But other than those, they seem to be pretty much the same.

Comment: In Ireland, I have never seen anything called an “English breakfast”. There is often something like a regular Irish breakfast (English breakfast with pudding but no beans) and a “full Irish breakfast” (with baked beans).

Comment: For completeness, if you ever see a "Scottish breakfast" advertised, it's like the above except it'll almost certainly include black pudding, the sausage should be a [lorne sausage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorne_sausage) (square and usually both pork and beef), and there will usually be a fried [potato scone](http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/1219633/potato-scones) instead of hash brown. Pretty rare outside of Scotland, sadly.

Answer (score 6):

It'll vary a little from place to place and on your establishment's interpretation.

However, a good definition comes from [businessdictionary.com](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/American-breakfast.html):

> A hotel breakfast that includes most or all of the following: two eggs
>   (fried or poached), sliced bacon or sausages, sliced bread or toast
>   with jam/jelly/butter, pancakes with syrup, cornflakes or other
>   cereal, coffee/tea, orange/grapefruit juice

[image: Wikipedia's picture for an American breakfast]
([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:American_breakfast_%28187066827%29.jpg))

If they're trying to include some unique American food, [biscuits and gravy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biscuits_and_gravy) is a fairly uniquely-American dish.

Comment: That photo makes me hungry! Isn't that Canadian bacon though? :)

Comment: @Itai [often sold in the US as just 'back bacon' or 'Irish bacon'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_bacon) :)

Comment: The term "Canadian bacon" is not understood outside North America. I've been to the US and Canada several times each and still can't remember what it's about.

Comment: @hippietrail It was supposedly [first popularized in Canada](http://www.torontolife.com/daily-dish/features-dish/2013/06/27/brief-history-bacon/) and later [brought to the US](http://kitchenproject.com/history/CanadianBacon/) via [England](http://www.epicmealtime.com/2013/01/14/my-theory-about-canadian-bacon-by-mook/), where it was named so for marketing purposes.

Comment: Canadian Bacon tends to be more circular - without the "panhandle" that these have. In Ireland, we'd call these "rashers", which are something of a hybrid, having a lean meaty Canadian-bacon-like part, with an almost fatty/crunchy US-bacon like "handle" attached. Canadian bacon is generally lean, and usually circular; US bacon is generally streaky, more crunchy, and _always_ in strips. (...except when crumbled into bits or pieces.)

Comment: I don't think pancakes are typically found in an English or Irish breakfast, that might be the main difference.

Comment: And the English one may have black pudding (shudders).

Comment: Also and English breakfast is unlikely to include 'home fries', which is almost an essential ingredient of an American Breakfast.

Comment: @DJClayworth: I mentioned "hash browns" similarly in another comment. I assume they must have something in common with "home fries".

Comment: Kind of. Fried potatoes, in smaller chunks.

Answer (score 3):

"An American Breakfast" is not a standardized item, especially from country to country  The only things it usually  seems to include is some form of bread, meat and eggs.  In S. Korea sometimes  the bread was  jam and coleslaw sandwiches. In Thailand sometimes  the meat was fish sausage. In Sweden the eggs are usually soft boiled, but they do throw in some baked beans to keep the English happy too.

Answer (score -1):

Both terms "American breakfast" and "Continental Breakfast" mean widely different things at different hotels and in different countries.  The only thing for sure is that when both are offered, the American breakfast is larger and has more items and heartier items than the Continental breakfast.

While the American breakfast usually includes eggs and meat (often pork), sometimes a Continental breakfast does as well.  Sometimes the Continental breakfast has only hard-boiled or scrambled eggs, while the American breakfast offers eggs any style or omelets.  It really does depend on the specific hotel.

Comment: I've never experienced that.  A "Continental Breakfast" at some U.S. hotels might be just bread, especially sweet pastries.  An "American Breakfast" almost always includes eggs and pork products.

Comment: @anomuse what you're describing is called a continental breakfast in the US. That would never be labeled an "American breakfast" by a hotel in the US.