# What is a continental breakfast and what other types of breakfasts are there?

Tags: food-and-drink, hotels, terminology

When I look for an hotel I often see the "continental breakfast" expression when they refer to their breakfasts.

I looked up the expression on Google and found:

> a light breakfast, typically consisting of coffee and bread rolls with butter and jam.

This contradicts my experience as I often find a lot more than that. There are often croissants, boiled eggs, scrambled eggs, juice, sausage, tomato, baked beans, etc.

[image]

**What is and what can I expect from a continental breakfast**? Does the industry have a different concept? And **what other kinds of breakfasts are there?**

Comment: I've seen it in several occasions on booking websites and hotels describing what they offer.

Comment: It is used quite widely in Europe and North America, but there is no common rule about what is included. I have also seen it offered with Japanese as other option, but other hotels there used 'American' instead.

Comment: It is sometimes distinguished from a "Full English" breakfast [and various other country names] which includes sausages, bacon, eggs, baked beans, various potato products, toast, *et c.*, and is a much more substantial meal.

Comment: Depending on how inexpensive your "hotel" is, a "continental breakfast" could consist of as little as a large thermos coffee dispenser and a box of doughnuts near the reception desk ...

Comment: Your description fits what you get in a B&B in Scotland when you order continental breakfast.

Comment: +1 Haha, I love this question. Always had it but never bothered to ask. :-)

Comment: I have never seen baked beans served for breakfast, let alone as part of a continental breakfast at a hotel.

Comment: @Robk I had it once, within the many things of a continental breakfast they also had baked beans as a buffet option together with a couple of other choices.

Comment: No love for the Italian breakfast. :(

Comment: @Calchas - That explains the "Continental" terminology. I've been wondering for years if there was some "Insular" breakfast that had proper eggs and bacon.

Comment: @RobK You're eating your breakfast in the wrong places. ;) A full English looks something like [this](http://imgur.com/8ZtjFbX). (Not my photography.)

Comment: Related: *[What is usually an American breakfast outside of the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23370)*

Comment: In Chile (and plenty other Spanish-speaking countries) a buffet breakfast is referred to as "American", and the "Continental" breakfast is basically coffee, toast and a glass of juice.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### Great Britain vs the Continent

Whenever something is referred to as "continental", you can be sure it's meant as the opposite of "British". The popular myth of the newspaper headline reading "Fog Blankets the Channel; Continent Cut Off" is another example of the attitude that spawned this dichotomy.

In this case, a *continental breakfast* is the opposite of a *full English breakfast* and that is where the term originated.

### Traditional English Breakfast

On the British Isles, a [full breakfast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_breakfast) (called a full English breakfast, full Scottish breakfast, full Welsh breakfast, or full Irish breakfast depending on the country; I'll use *English* in my answer since that's the most common term), is a warm — mostly fried — breakfast. Its exact constituents vary, but it usually consists of scrambled eggs, sausages and bacon, baked beans, fried tomatoes, and fried potatoes, sometimes with black and white pudding, or with fried up leftover vegetables from last night. It's quite a heavy meal.

In the rest of Europe, [breakfast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakfast#Europe) is usually mainly bread with cheese, slices of meat, or sweet or savoury spreads. Breakfast cereals, sometimes. The only ingredients that are usually eaten warm are eggs or porridge. It is a bit lighter meal than an English breakfast

Hot beverages such as coffee or tea are common to both.

### In Hotels

The main difference between a continental breakfast and a full (English) breakfast is cold vs. hot.

A continental breakfast can be served cold, eggs having been boiled beforehand. The only hot ingredients might be the beverages — coffee, tea, hot chocolate.  This reduces cost for the hotel and allows for the breakfast to be served in just about any room; it's not unusual to see the hotel bar being used for this if the hotel serves only a continental breakfast.
The hotel doesn't need any cooks to be present, just waiting staff to serve it.

If a hotel serves both a continental breakfast and a full English breakfast, the latter may be offered at a premium, since the costs to the hotel are higher as well.

If you've had a continental breakfast that included scrambled eggs and other hot dishes, it most likely was a breakfast buffet, where the hotel offers something extra to its guests, ending up a bit in the direction of a full English.

Comment: The use of the word continental is much wider than just Europe. I have seen it in the USA and Canada. Not sure, but I think I have also seen it in Japan, (for a general Western breakfast) and Australia and New Zealand.

Comment: @Willeke of course, but that's where it originated.

Comment: A continental breakfast can contain hot porridge and hot tea or coffee, so hot vs. cold is not quite accurate.

Comment: @gerrit I've clarified a bit; originally I had left out the beverages. I've never gotten hot porridge as part of a continental breakfast _in a hotel_, though, so I disagree with you on that.

Comment: @Willeke I've edited a bit to reflect the origin of the term.

Comment: @SQB I have received it in a *continental breakfast buffet* in Germany and Sweden.

Comment: @SQB the method of cooking the eggs would normally be fried but these days choices are usually offered. Scrambled is most certainly NOT the default option for a genuine Full <insert country here> Breakfast except in buffet style breakfasts, where it is best avoided anyway as it is generally badly cooked, rubbery slop. Also hash browns are an American invention and NOT considered part of a traditional breakfast, although fried potatoes may be.

Also, on the continent cold meats are a frequent addition to breakfast as well as cheese, as are museli and yogurt.

Comment: @StevePettifer corrected. I (incorrectly) omitted the sliced meat because I couldn't come up with a single word for "stuff you put on bread", which is called _broodbeleg_ in Dutch.

Comment: In my college dorm cafeteria continental breakfast meant they stopped serving the bacon and eggs and only beverages and some basic breads were available. I'm sure this is just an American misuse of the term.

Comment: In great parts of the rest of Europe, breakfast is usually also cereals (common in most parts) and porridge (especially common in the northern parts). Especially in Scandinavia, cereals and porridge are traditionally more common as everyday breakfast options than bread. Particularly pastry and bread served with meat toppings would be common for Sunday breakfast, but not for everyday breakfast.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet edited to reflect that.

Comment: @SQB I love that you have a word for that!

Answer (score 65):

Continental tends to refer to a cold breakfast, as opposed to a cooked breakfast.  Usually it is breads, cereals, drinks, but each hotel will dress it up as they please.

American breakfasts tend to be cooked eggs, breakfast meat, breads, drinks.

Full or Cooked breakfast (often named locally ie Japanese breakfast, etc) tend to be whatever is commonly cooked for breakfast in the country the hotel is located in.

Buffets, well most folks know what a buffet is ....

But as mentioned in my continental description, each hotel can and will dress up their meal offering as they see fit for all of the above "categories".  Plus different cultural expectations will contribute to the final menu.

Comment: Some hotels will have cold meats and cheeses included in a continental breakfast; on top of pastries, breads and cereals.

Comment: It may still be useful to mention what types of foods the buffet will offer, not just implying the change in style.  It usually offers full American breakfast foods.

Comment: @Pysis - A buffet will have different items in different countries and many do not include "full American breakfast foods" (whatever that may entail to you).

Comment: Country was mentioned and implied.  I can attest to many buffets marketed as such, not as a contenintal breakfast, even if the serving stations were similar, for a high or even 100% of hotels I have been to that mention it.

Comment: @Pysis - I see no mention of country either direct or implied in the OP (or in my answer).  The context of the question is in regard to hotel industry use of the terms (an industry which is global).

Comment: I was at least providing my experience from the USA.

Comment: In the USA, I've seen continental breakfast include toaster and Eggo waffles (or the generic equivalent), or a waffle iron and some batter, so it isn't always "cold" but is something that doesn't require a chef in a kitchen to prepare

Comment: Geez, the nitpicking.  I said usually, tends, etc not does, always, etc.  We are talking about generalized ideas here, not exact menus.

Answer (score 32):

Here are some breakfasts I have encountered. Of course, each hotel adds and removes items as they wish.

Edited according to some comments (especially the ones about the boiled tomato - I now realize how mistaken I was).

- Continental - very modest; consisting of a hot drink, bread and/or pastry, butter, jam, possibly juice, sometimes more.
- English - Eggs, sausage, fried bacon, baked beans, grilled tomato, cereal, tea or coffee.
- Irish (often called "Full Irish") - similar to English, with black/white pudding (which may be found in the English too) and no cereal.
- American - large amounts of eggs, fried bacon, cereal, pastries, sometimes waffles, coffee.
- Israeli - large buffet with eggs (often made to order), vegetables, fruit, cheese, cereal, and more (no meat).

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a continental breakfast buffet that didn't include a selection of cereals and juice. Most will also have fruit and pastries; many offer some cold cuts too.

Comment: Boiled rather than fried tomato? You've been had. Wherever served you that was lying quite freely.

Comment: What about kedgeree?  Or kippers?  Or Eggs Benedict (personally I prefer Royale)?  Or a good old Omelette?  Or smoked salmon and scrambled eggs on toast?  Or any other number of cooked breakfasts that don't fall under a particular national name?  Continental in my experience is, as you say, cold (but I agree with Henning it usually includes cereals, fruit and pastries—sometimes yogurts etc too); but not anything cooked.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I've seen in the US -more than once - a "continental breakfast" consisting of instant coffee with a microwave to heat your water, and a box of donuts.

Comment: In my experience (traveling *in America*), a *continental breakfast* is *not* a "buffet" - there are "continental breakfasts" (coffee and pastries, OJ *if* you're lucky), and "breakfast buffets" that range from minimal to lavish - two entirely different animals

Comment: English (and Irish) breakfasts are typically served with tea, not coffee.

Comment: @FKEinternet I've seen "continental buffet" as well.

Comment: @MattThrower I've never seen anywhere in the UK that didn't give the option of coffee

Comment: @ChrisH Option, sure. But the default is usually tea unless you specify. It is an English breakfast after all :)

Comment: @MattThrower unlike with a cream tea (when I ask "but can I have it with coffee?") I've never been presented with a default, at breakfast.  Often the drinks are self-service in the places I stay anyway, but even going into a cafe I've always been asked "tea or coffee?" if there's a hot drink included.

Comment: Downvoted. This is simply inaccurate. As @Ben points out, an English breakfast has a grilled or fried tomato. Cereal is absolutely not an essential component, nor is coffee. And the the distinction between an English and Irish breakfasts really is just where the breakfast is served. An English breakfast is just as likely as an Irish one to include black pudding.

Comment: A typical Israeli breakfast is actually very rarely a buffet, it's typically a lot of smaller plates.  This looks about right: http://www.israel-food-guide.com/images/israeli_breakfast_cafe.jpg - Israeli breakfasts are only buffets in hotels - and typically the really good ones won't serve it buffet anyway.

Comment: +1 to the pastries and coffee (and milk and/or juice if you're lucky) at lower-end motels in the US. Some places actually have "deluxe" pastries (danishes, cinnamon rolls, etc) that they put in a plastic pastry case, others are cheap enough to just put out a box of donuts and rolls from the donut shop around the corner and not even bother trying to hide the box. In either case this is often proudly and prominently billed as a "complimentary continental breakfast"

Comment: Don't forget [grits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grits) in the American breakfast. *Grits are usually served with other flavorings as a breakfast dish, usually savory.* Don't forget the more usual **tea** with the English breakfast. And further to the comment from MJeffryes, black pudding is a northern England dish.

Comment: The essential ingredient of a proper English breakfast is *fat* - fried sausage, fried bacon, fried mushrooms, fried eggs, fried black pudding (in the north of England), fried bread (not grilled toast!), etc. *Boiled* tomato? UGH!!! Fry the thing!!!

Comment: You missed tea in the English breakfast ;)

Comment: @MJeffryes. My understanding is that English breakfasts have black pudding in northern England, but not in the south. Irish breakfasts will *always* include both black and white pudding (white being unknown in Britain). An Ulster Fry will include farls (soda farls and/or potato farls).

Comment: @TRiG Yes these are all ok generalisations, but I can definitely find you many places in the south serving black pudding. My point is that many of the components are somewhat optional and making a hard and fast distinction between the two is futile (not to mention the existence of full Welsh and Scottish breakfasts, which are also broadly similar).

Comment: @MJeffryes In many places they will serve you heated tinned plum tomatoes as part of an 'English' breakfast. Personally I hate tomatoes so never have them (or mushrooms). I am in full agreement with the rest of your point though. 

WeatherVane - where black pudding originated from is irrelevant as it is widely eaten throughout the country, and as it is actually a blood pudding it has many close relatives across Europe.

Comment: Doesn't the Irish one have potatoes ( scones or farls )?

Answer (score 13):

I have only had two kinds of breakfasts in the hotels that I have visited, the continental breakfast, which across all the properties I have visited is:

- bakery items
- fruits (seasonal)
- coffee or tea

The variety of each may vary depending on the type of location you are in and the locality. For example in some areas, a continental breakfast includes an egg dish of some sort (boiled, omelette, fried to order, etc.)

The other type is the "breakfast buffet" which includes:

- fruits
- bakery items
- a deli section (cold meats and cuts)
- a dairy section (yogurt, milk, cheeses of various varieties)
- drinks:

  - milk
  - fruit juices
- coffee, tea and espresso stations
- a cereal station
- a condiment station
- a warm breakfast station (usually, made to order omelettes or eggs)
- a buffet line, which consists of:

  - eggs (scrambled and boiled, usually)
  - beans
  - breakfast meat
  - a carb item (usually grits)
  - any regional specialities
  - a vegetarian option

Depending on the restaurant chosen and the hotel locality, you may see different items or areas for specific dietary needs. At one hotel I saw a specific area for vegan items for breakfast.

At a hotel in Islamabad (capital of Pakistan) I had in addition to the omelette station, a *paratha* station (its a hot leavened fried bread with butter) which is traditional to South Asia; and sweet meats.

Answer (score 8):

While reading other answers here, I am discovering new types of breakfasts. Never realized there are so many differences between UK counties and regions. Most hotels specify the type of breakfast they offer either to *establish value* or to *cater a certain clientele*. The point is that the name of the breakfast is not the menu, but an indication of the types of things offered.

The ones I know of are:

- **Continental**: Hot coffee and tea, plus an assortment of breads and cold bready pastries, things like croissants and danishes some to mind since *Continental* refers to the continent of Europe. An American hotel offering a continental breakfast usually offers bagels and donuts, sometimes with something similar to poundcake. Juice and milt are often available too.
- **American**: Coffee, tea, juice, milk almost certainly plus warm food with eggs, bacon, sausages and potatoes (hash browns or *home* fries).
- **English**: Also with coffee, tea, juice, milk and hot egg and meat based breakfast, plus commonly British items such as beans and tomatoes.
- **South American**: Coffee, tea, juice, bread, fruits and jam or marmalade.
- **Asian**: Tea, often coffee too, plus congee with an assortment of toppings such as boiled eggs, fried fish, steamed vegetables and sauces. Depending on with your are in South East or North East Asia, dumplings or soup (or both) make a frequent appearance.
- **Japanese**: Tea and coffee with steamed rice, cooked fish and broth plus a number of garnishes such as pickled vegetables, tofu, boiled egg to add to your soup or eat with the rice.

Half of these were covered by previous answers already but other regions do have their own and the closer you get to the region the more specific things get. In Asia, hotels often offer a buffet with each type getting its own section. So while you are eating breakfast in Asia, hotels catering to international travelers can still offer a section of American and another for Continental breakfast, plus one for local type of breakfast.

Note that I do not consider *buffet* to be a type of breakfast. Most breakfasts listed above can be served or offered as buffet or even a hybrid. In South America for example, many hotels offer a buffet of bread and fruits but will serve one or two, made-to-order, eggs. In Taiwan, I was often given a set breakfast plus access to a table with additional rice and congee but nothing else.

In Brazil, breakfasts were different than in the rest of South America. I don't know if it is called Brazilian breakfast but it consists mostly of large amount of fruits, eggs, tapioca, bread accompanied by coffee and juice.

Comment: In hotel parlance, _buffet_ refers to a serve yourself type breakfast whereas a _cooked_ or _full_ is served to you.  _Buffet_ will often combine multiple breakfast types.

Comment: Usually we say *buffet* or *a la carte*. Sometimes people also use *cooked-to-order* but that can mean something that as not been prepared in advance. A buffet can have many *cooked* items yet be self-served, so obviously the language is being overloaded in English.

Comment: We are not talking about what we say (me, you, etc), we are talking about terms used by hotels to describe food is provided with a room.

Comment: If you are doing breakfast lists, you've missed off (at least) the sort of breakfasts common in Germany, Austria, Switzerland (German speaking) consisting of cold meats, cheeses, bread, etc.

Comment: The list if not really about which place eats what but more about how hotels describe their breakfasts. The actual contents of a continental breakfast in a US hotel may be very different from one in Europe (and indeed with vary between states and countries within those regions).

Answer (score 6):

I add to the list of Ugoren, as he already wrote obviously every business change items.

Colazione / Italian breakfast: coffee or cappuccino, tea available, biscuits and pastries, bread - butter - jam. To my experience nowadays in hotels and pensions there is always at least one juice, eggs (although in small properties you can only boil them, or they are served 3' and 8'), cheese, ham and salami, cereals and muesli, yoghurt, fruits. It was the reason I THOUGHT this to be a continental breakfast, because is not what we italians have in everyday life.
Also, I can imagine that a very small and cheap property might serve an Italian breakfast similar to that italians do everyday at the bars (intended as business itself) and therefore be limited to coffee, caffelatte or cappuccino for the drink, pastries.

Europe in general: Experience tells me that in most of Europe the hotel breakfast is like the extended one I mentioned just the very lines above. Obviously the precise items may vary according to the country: cheeses, salumeria, bread are different everywhere, and so can be even with a single country, e.g. Italy.

Frühstück (Austria), similar to the above in structure, very different in details. Cheese and wurst dominated (there can be three sorts of both) over the sweets, that are limited to jam and bread rolls. Huge choice of breads. Egg can be as you like, either there is a cook or you do it. Again cereals, muesli, yoghurt. Typical in the broad choice of meat and leaver spreads.

---

Reading again the question I found that I and the OP have the same impression. It seems that a continental breakfast is rarely served, or the definition he found is wrong. See also my comment.

Comment: The more limited breakfast I had to date, both were in England and US. I do refer to choice, not to calories or size.

Comment: CAUTION:  The English word "marmalade" means specifically jam made from citrus fruit (specifically oranges unless qualified as "lemon marmalade", "grapefruit marmalade" etc).  Is that what you meant?  (I ask because the German word "die Marmelade" is a false friend - it is better translated as "jam").  In Germany and Switzerland I would expect a few sorts of jam (for example: marmalade, strawberry, blackcurrant).

Comment: @Martin Bonner. Yes, you are right. I couldn't recall the word jam. The same with marmellata in italian. There is also confettura (confiture) which brings in more confusion.I will correct. Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by eggs served 3' and 8' ?

Comment: @aslum. Hardness expressed in minutes. :) Cooking time.

Answer (score 3):

The two basic kinds of breakfasts are "continental," and "country." That is, "continental" refers to the European continent, while "country" refers to individual countries.

A "continental" breakfast is distinguished from a "country" breakfast by the lack of cooking. It consists mainly of "cold" items such as "breads": rolls, croissants, danish, etc. plus cold drinks such as juice or milk. Tea and coffee are the only "hot" items served because the waitstaff can serve this (and "cold" items) without the help of a chef. One variation of "continental" is "South American," which includes cold local fruits such as papayas, mangoes and guavas. Some European continental settings feature cold "northern" fruits such as honeydew and cantalope.

A "country" breakfast features hot food, requires a chef, and varies by country. An "American" breakfast might feature fried eggs, bacon, ham or sausage, and potatoes or hot cereal. An "English" breakfast will have eggs,meat and potatoes, like an American breakfast, and also include beans and other typically English vegetables. an "Asian" breakfast might substitute fish for meat and use Asian-style vegetables  (all cooked).

Comment: As a northern European, I'm somewhat amused to hear cantaloupes being described as a northern fruit ;)