# AirBNB "Breakfast provided" exact meaning

Tags: romania, airbnb

I booked an AirBNB with the mentioned feature, which I interpreted as "breakfast is included in the price". The host informed me, though that I have to pay extra if I want breakfast.

Since I'm not a regular user of AirBNB, it may be that my interpretation is wrong, so I would like to ask: is this the usual meaning of "provided breakfast" (i.e., you have the possibility to get breakfast for extra money)?

Comment: In what country is this? It may be a case of poor translation ("breakfast available" vs. "breakfast complimentary"). Besides, what constitutes one or another kind of [breakfast](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23370) differs from place to place.

Comment: The country is Romania, now I added the tag for it. However, I would be interested in the answer even if it varies among countries. (E.g. if the answer is "in Romania this always means breakfast for extra money, but in Bangladesh it usually means it is included in the price", I'm interested in that answer too, even though I'm in Romania at the moment.)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how AirBNB works for hosts, but I imagined that they just tick boxes, so they don't have to translate these features for themselves (hence "poor translation" not possible)

Comment: The host isn't entering the amenities, but the host can misinterpret the purpose of a form input, and thus check the wrong box.

Answer (score 7):

The host is responsible for creating and maintaining the listing. AirBnb do not have any input into the listing.

‘Breakfast is provided’ is listed under ‘Special Amenities’ - ticking the box means the host provides breakfast as part of the cost. If the host wants to charge for it as an added extra, they need to indicate this on their listing with prices and then they can charge for it through the AirBnb Resolution Centre (in accordance with AirBnb policy that guests should always pay hosts through AirBnb, not directly to the host).

I would expect the host to state what type of breakfast (basic, full cooked etc) is provided within the listing description. If there is no mention of an extra fee for breakfast anywhere within the property listing, you should contact AirBnb Support to resolve the issue.

Source: I am an AirBnb host.